# Can we make TeX instructions easier to find?

Tags: discussion

I go to the site banner and click on "help" and then "help center".
I see a search box which promises to search the help pages.
I type in "TeX" and hit `Search`.
No results.

This would seem to be a barrier for n00bs (I'm making this post because someone is asking me for a reference on how TeX works on this site).

Can we improve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You stumbled on the unfortunate fact that our [notation help page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) did not include the word "TeX". It did include both "LaTeX" and "MathJax" so searching for either of those would have found it. Anyway, I've fixed that by expanding the help page.

Comment: Thanks. It works now.